# Compare two Arrays synchronously in Java

Tags: java, arrays, integer, compare, version

I'm working on something that compares two versions split by a regex "//.".

What I'm struggling with is trying figure out a way of comparing two values in an array "synchronously", in order to see if a value in one is greater than the other. Say for instance I have:

```
int[] newerVersion = {2, 4, 7}; 
int[] olderVersion = {1, 2, 0};
```

In this case I would be trying to work out if 2 > 1 and 4 > 2 and so on.

The code I have right now can reverse the order of the arrays by mapping them into a List and doing Collections.reverse(). Am I on the right track? Any ideas on how to write something like this?

Answer (score 2):

Just iterate over the arrays - no need to use Lists or Collections etc.

```
boolean bools = new boolean[newVersion.length];
for(int i = 0; i < newVersion.length && i < oldVersion.length; i++) {
    bools[i] = newVersion[i] > oldVersion[i];
}
```

Comment: Yes, but the problem with this is that if the version was say 1.9.1, and the version on the server was 1.8.2, then it would say there was a newer version available (1.8.2), which would be out of date.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the array

```
boolean check = false;
for(int i = 0; i < newerVersion.length; i++) {
      if(newerVersion[i] > oldVersion[i]) {
            check = true;
            break;
      }
      else if(newerVersion[i] < olderVersion[i]) {
             break;
      }   
}
```

check is true if there is newer version.